# Como Puedo Iterar un Objeto C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una duda. Como puedo iterar objetos en C#?

```
foreach (var test in prueba)
{
   intArray[1] = (string)test.Peticion1;
   intArray[2] = (string)test.Peticion2;
   intArray[3] = (string)test.Peticion3;
   intArray[4] = (string)test.Peticion4;
   intArray[5] = (string)test.Peticion5;
}
```

Mi getter a un Json web

```
class GetJson
{
    public object Peticion1 { get; set; }
    public object Peticion2 { get; set; }
    public object Peticion3 { get; set; }
    public object Peticion4 { get; set; }
    public object Peticion5 { get; set; }
}
```

Si tengo 50 líneas en un Json no se como puedo hacer la iteración tanto en la clase GetJson como en el foreach, además, de mantener el casting de los Arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La **clase GetJson** en vez de tener n-campos que representen las n-peticiones, podría tener una sola propiedad que sea una lista de objetos(o el tipo de dato que te interese).

Ahora te quedaría así:

```
class GetJson
{
    public List<object> Peticiones{ get; set; }
}
```

Ahora cada elemento de la lista sería un objeto.

Y una posible forma de recorrerlo sería:

```
for(int i = 0; i < prueba.Peticiones.Count(); i++)
{
   intArray[i] = (string)test.Peticiones.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Se recorren las peticiones y se guardan en el arreglo en la posición del índice dada por la **variable i** del **ciclo for**.

Comment: funciona perfectamente,solo tuve que añadir `i++` en el bucle,gracias